# What am trying to run batch from developer console but getting System.StringException: Invalid id: SUPPLIER_LEVELS-LEVEL_2

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

i am trying to count account and contact record from campaign object by grouping by external unique field and created campaign account member junction object which has look up relationship with campaign and account .Below is batch class which sending me exception email

> (Apex script unhandled exception by user/organization: xxxxxxxxxxxz7Tb/xxxxxxxxxxxCqPg Source organization: xxxxxxxtmhf (null) Failed to process batch for class 'BatchCountCampaignMember' for job id '7070S00000HnM0U'
>
> **caused by: System.StringException: Invalid id: SUPPLIER_LEVELS-LEVEL_2**

---

```
global class BatchCountCampaignMember implements 
    Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {
    
    // instance member to retain state across transactions
    global Integer recordsProcessed = 0;
    public Map<Id,Integer> mapExternalIdToNumberOfRecord = new Map<Id,Integer>();
    public  Set<String> setExternalIdsUniques = new Set<String>();

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(
            'select Id,Campaign_External_Id__c,(Select Id,Campaign__c,Customer__c  from Campaign_Account_Members__r) '+
            ' from Campaign');
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Campaign> scope){
        // process each batch of records  
        Map<Id,Integer> mapAccountIdToNumberOfContact = new Map<Id,Integer>();
        Set<String> setExternalIds = new Set<String>();
        Set<Id> setAccountIds = new Set<Id>();
        for(Campaign  objCamp : scope){
            for(Campaign_Account_Member__c objCampaignAccountMembers : objCamp.Campaign_Account_Members__r){
                setAccountIds.add(objCamp.Campaign_External_Id__c);  
                setAccountIds.add(objCampaignAccountMembers.Customer__c);
            }   
        }
        
        List<Account> listAccounts = [Select Id,(Select id from Contacts) from Account Where ID IN : setAccountIds limit 50000];
        for(Account objAccount : listAccounts){
            if(!mapAccountIdToNumberOfContact.containsKey(objAccount.Id)){
                if(objAccount.Contacts.size() != 0)
                mapAccountIdToNumberOfContact.put(objAccount.Id,objAccount.Contacts.size());
                else
                mapAccountIdToNumberOfContact.put(objAccount.Id,0);    
            }  
        }
        list<Campaign> listCampaignUpdate = new list<Campaign>();
        for(Campaign  objCamp : scope){
            Set<Id> setTempAccountIds = new Set<Id>();
            Integer numberOfContacts= 0;
            
            for(Campaign_Account_Member__c objCampaignAccountMembers : objCamp.Campaign_Account_Members__r){
                setAccountIds.add(objCamp.Campaign_External_Id__c);  
                setTempAccountIds.add(objCampaignAccountMembers.Customer__c);
                if(mapAccountIdToNumberOfContact.containsKey(objCampaignAccountMembers.Customer__c))
                    numberOfContacts =  numberOfContacts + mapAccountIdToNumberOfContact.get(objCampaignAccountMembers.Customer__c);
            }
            objCamp.Number_of_Account__c = setTempAccountIds.size();
            objCamp.Number_Of_contacts__c = numberOfContacts;
            listCampaignUpdate.add(objCamp);
        }
        if(!listCampaignUpdate.isEmpty())
            update listCampaignUpdate;
       
    }    

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        System.debug(recordsProcessed + ' records processed. Shazam!');
        AsyncApexJob job = [SELECT Id, Status, NumberOfErrors, 
            JobItemsProcessed,
            TotalJobItems, CreatedBy.Email
            FROM AsyncApexJob
            WHERE Id = :bc.getJobId()];
        // call some utility to send email
       
    }    


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Is Campaign_Account_Member__c.Campaign_External_Id__c` a field of type String? Because if so you're throwing an exception when calling `setAccountIds.add(objCamp.Campaign_External_Id__c);` and trying assign an Id variable with a generic string value. All Ids are Strings, but not all Strings are Ids. Also you're not referencing the `Set<String> setExternalIds = new Set<String>();` variable anywhere. Perhaps you meant to use that collection instead?